# C Programming Occurrences of an Integers in an Text File

Tags: c, arrays

> Problem: Write a program that reads all integers that are in the range
>   of 0 to 100, inclusive from an input file named: a.txt and counts how
>   many occurrences of each are in the file. After all input has been
>   processed, display all the values with the number of occurrences that
>   were in are in the input file.
>
> Note: The program ignores any number less than 0 or greater than 100.
>   Note: Do not display zero if a number is not in the file. Hints: An
>   array of size 101 is good enough. A number in the file plays the role
>   of an index.
>
> For example: Suppose the content of the file: a.txt is as follows:

```
99 2 99 
3 
-12 80 12 33 
3 99 100 1234 84
```

> The display output is:

```
2 has occurred: 1 times,
3 has occurred: 2 times,
12 has occurred: 1 times,
33 has occurred: 1 times,
80 has occurred: 1 times,
84 has occurred: 1 times,
99 has occurred: 3 times,
100 has occurred: 1 times
```

Here is the code that I have right now:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *inFile;
    int count = 1, num[101];

    inFile = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        fscanf(inFile, "%d", &num[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        if(num[i] == i) {
            printf("%i has occurred: %d times\n", i, count);
            count++;
        }
    }

    fclose(inFile);
}
```

Output:
2 has occured: 1 times

Hello, I'm trying to do this assignment for my C Programming class due Sunday at midnight, but I'm having trouble trying to print all of the numbers from the array with their occurrences. In my code, I first declared int count to increase the number of occurrences if the number is found more than once in the text file and created an array size of 101. Then, I used a for loop to read the text file and store all the numbers from 1-100 into the array. The second for loop, followed by an if statement is to compare the numbers from the array. Even though this is a test program, we are supposed to be able to do this with all data values. Hope this is a good enough explanation, thank you.

Comment: You seem to have an error in your logic. The array num[101] is supposed to store the count of each element, where the array is indexed by each number from 0 to 100

Comment: You need to use the `i` from the first for loop to know how many entries are in the `num` array. Also you're starting the indices for `num` from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

Instead of reading each value into `num`, You want to use your `num` array to keep the count of each number seen in the file.

```
int main() {
    FILE* inFile;
    int value = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int num[101] = { 0 }; // zero-init this array

    inFile = fopen("a.txt", "r");

    if (inFile == NULL) {
        printf("unable to open file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    result = fscanf(inFile, "%d", &value);
    while (result == 1) {

        printf("Just read: %d\n", value);

        if ((value >= 0) && (value <= 100)) {
            num[value] = num[value] + 1;  // num[value]++
        }
        result = fscanf(inFile, "%d", &value);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (num[i] > 0) {
            printf("%i has occurred: %d times\n", i, num[i]);
        }
    }

    fclose(inFile);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be an infinite loop in the while loop @selbie. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but is the while loop basically increasing the number of occurrences in the text file?

Comment: Aside from the typo I made (and just corrected), the program will run until it reach an end of file condition from the `inFile`.

Comment: Hmmm... What happens in the event of a *matching-failure* with `while (result != EOF)`? That loop may go on for a very long time and your screen may fill with `"Just read: <some strange value>"` as attempts are made to read the offending character in what becomes an endless loop. Suggest `while (result == 1) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answer by [@selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458/selbie), from my answer to your earlier question [How do I get the counter to work...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232015/how-to-i-get-the-counter-to-work-in-this-c-program), you can apply the same principals to filling a *Frequency Array* here. In this case you simply use `n` as an *index* instead of a counter.

For example with your index `n` and your array `num` declared (*and initialized all zero*), you would simply read all integers in the file and check if the value `n` was between `0 <= n <= 100` and if so , update the value at the index `n` in your `num` array by one, e.g. `num[n]++;`. You could do it like:

```
    int n = 0;              /* index */
    int num[NELEM] = {0};   /* array */
    ...
    while (fscanf(myFile, "%d", &n) == 1)   /* read each int */
        if (0 <= n && n <= 100)             /* if 0 <= n <= 100 */
            num[n]++;                       /* increment value at index */
```

Then for your output, you just handle your special check on `num[0]` to determine whether to output that index, and then loop from `1-NELEM` outputting the frequency of occurrence of each value, e.g.

```
    if (num[0])     /* check if 0 found, output if so */
        printf ("num[%3d] occurred %3d times\n", 0, num[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < NELEM; i++) /* output counts for 1-100 */
        printf ("num[%3d] occurred %3d times\n", i, num[i]);
```

The complete example could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NELEM 101   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = 0;              /* index */
    int num[NELEM] = {0};   /* array */
    /* read filename from 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *myFile = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!myFile) {  /* validate myfile is open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-myfile");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(myFile, "%d", &n) == 1)   /* read each int */
        if (0 <= n && n <= 100)             /* if 0 <= n <= 100 */
            num[n]++;                       /* increment value at index */

    if (myFile != stdin)        /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (myFile);

    if (num[0])     /* check if 0 found, output if so */
        printf ("num[%3d] occurred %3d times\n", 0, num[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < NELEM; i++) /* output counts for 1-100 */
        printf ("num[%3d] occurred %3d times\n", i, num[i]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With 500 random integers in a file, you would get output similar to:

```
$ ./bin/fscanffreq dat/500_rand_0-100.txt
num[  0] occurred   3 times
num[  1] occurred   8 times
num[  2] occurred   7 times
num[  3] occurred   2 times
num[  4] occurred   1 times
num[  5] occurred   4 times
num[  6] occurred   3 times
num[  7] occurred   5 times
num[  8] occurred   6 times
num[  9] occurred   4 times
num[ 10] occurred   6 times
...
num[ 95] occurred   6 times
num[ 96] occurred   4 times
num[ 97] occurred   6 times
num[ 98] occurred   2 times
num[ 99] occurred   5 times
num[100] occurred   6 times
```

(**note:** if `num[0]` was `0`, it would not be displayed)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.